# Service state is reported incorrectly

Tags: c#

I installed my c# application as windows service using the following command,

Installutil.exe

The installation is done in 32 bit machine.And the c# application is using 8088 port.
After installing the service the service property has changed to Automatic.
When the system restart the service also will be get restarted.
But some times it shows started as status ,but actually it is in stopped state and we need to manually start the service.
Can some one tell me what went wrong in this.

Thanks in advance.

sangita

Comment: Really depends on your service. You should create logs of your service's OnStart event and see what happens in there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chances are that an unhandled exception occurred and the service process has terminated as result.

You should add logging to identify what unhandled exceptions occur and fix them.

Comment: The application uses UI for two different sites.Means same c# application is used for two different databases,and it is accesing depending upon the credentials.